# How to automate this object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests

This is my Test Object:

```
let testObj = {
    addressOne: "delhi",
    addressTwo: "varansi",
    cityCode: "IN-BR-DH",
    countryCode: "IN",
    domainId: 75,
    emailId: "emailId3{{i}}@gmail.com",
    firstName: "automate",
    lastName: "string",
    mobileCode: "+91",
    mobileNumber: "{{userMobileNumber}}",
    orgId: 170,
    roleId: 4,
    stateCode: "IN-BR",
    userName: "automation98",
    zipCode: 656689
}
```

I want to create 15 scenarios in which each value of this object will be 'null'

This code prints all the keys and values:

```
for(let key of Object.keys(testObj) ){
    console.log(key, testObj[key])
}
```

But I want something which sets

```
all keys and values in first iteration,
addressOne = null in the second iteration,
addressTwo = null in the third iteration,
cityCode  = null in fourth iteration,
```

and so on..

Please suggest a way to do it.

Comment: `objProps = Object.keys(testObj); for (let current = 0; current < objProps.length; current++) for (let i = 0; i < objProps.length; i++) { console.log(objProps[i], i === current ? null : testObj[objProps[i]]); }`

Comment: I'm sorry I want the first iteration to display all the keys and values. null starts from second one. Sorry for phrasing the question incorrectly @ASDFGerte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one key at each iteration and set it to `null`. Important is to create a clone of the object. The following code creates one object at each iteration.

```
for (let key of Object.keys(testObj)) {
    let clone = {
        ...testObj,
        [key]: null
    };
    console.log(clone);
}
```

This code uses spread operator and computed properties. These are new javascript features you may want to replace with older ones.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want the first iteration to display all the keys and values. null starts from second one. Sorry for phrasing the question incorrectly, I have edited it now. Please check